# Regular expression, required field only with alphanumeric

Tags: asp.net, regex

So how do I add that it should not have empty field in this same line including my other validation for alphanumeric reg ex.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$
```

I tried this and didn't work

```
^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$ | /\S/
```

This is for validation controls

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="userLocationValidation" runat="server" 
      ControlToValidate="userLocation" 
      ValidationExpression="/\S/"
      ErrorMessage="Only use letters from the english alphabet a-z">                                                               
  </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Your regex will not match an empty string. Feel free to define "empty field".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9 _]+[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$
```

The '+' says one or more, so empty fields will fail.

Comment: The second character class `[A-Za-z0-9]` is not optional, so the regex will not match an empty string anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 _]+$
```

`+` means at least one

if you mean at least one not white-space character something like

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 _]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[a-zA-Z0-9 _]*$
```